# success function not firing in verify dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some plain jane JQuery/Javascript.

The success function is not firing despite a 200 OK response.

The error function IS firing. Although I don't know why. The server side code executes properly.

I do get this warning in the console:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

Here is the code:

```
    <script>

        window.verifyDelete = function(){

            var dialogBox = $("#dialog-confirm").dialog(
                    {
                        resizable: false,
                        height: 300,
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            "Delete all items": function() {
                                $("#response").html( "" );

                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: '/MyApp/reset',
                                    success: window.updateJsonResponse,
                                    error: window.onErrorDisplayAlert,
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    async: true
                                });

                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            "Cancel": function() {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
               dialogBox.html("<p>The following items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered:"
                            + "<ul><li>Groups</li><li>People</li><li>Reports</li></ul></p>"
                            + "<p>Are you sure?</p>");
        };

        window.updateJsonResponse = function(){
            $("#response").html( "The database was sucessfully reset." );
        };

        window.onErrorDisplayAlert = function(){
            alert( "Javascript is hard to debug!");
        };

    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried `success: function ( data ){
            $("#response").html( "The database was sucessfully reset." );
        }, ...` ?

Comment: is any of this code wrapped in a closure, like load event handler? If so `updateJsonResponse` wouldn't be global...try `success: updateJsonResponse`. Are any errors thrown?

Comment: @UDB - Yes I tried that.

Comment: @charlietfl - I updated the code to make it clearer.

Comment: @Morre - I agree. I made it more consistent and the scope more obvious.

Comment: OK..assume you have no errors thrown?? Is this a cross domain request? If so, can get a 200 but if API is not CORS enabled and not returning jsonp browser can't use data and `success` callback won't fire, neither will error callback...should also throw in an error callback to see what it tells you

Comment: add an `error` callback and see what's the error

Comment: @BeNdErR: Just did, and yes that does get fired. Although why I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatype is set to 'json'.

If the content-type returned by the server is not json despite the successful response JQuery will consider that an error.

Welcome to the silent world of javascript exception handling!

Comment: @Guido Anselmi: Thanks! That was it. I set it to text/html by default. This was a copy and paste from another function that DID return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `server side code return a string or something apart from json` which **jquery would treat like error** and the error callback would get fired.

Try sending the data as **JSON object from server side** code. Make sure to **check your response text in Jquery's response (success/ error) both** in order to see what is received and then also **check if that is json**. If not alter the datatype accordingly.